# Make VS 2008 Auto Deploy SQL Server CE 3.5 When Debugging on Windows Mobile 5.0 Device

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, sql-server-ce, windows-mobile-5.0

How do you make VS 2008 automatically install SQL Server CE 3.5 when debugging (F5) a CF app on a windows Mobile 5.0 device?

VS used to do this automatically, but now it stopped and I don't know why. I have changed the structure of my solution and the projects, but it is still using SQL Server CE 3.5. It used to also install the Query Analyzer as well which was useful. I frequently uninstall all the programs on the device or do hard reboots so installing this manually is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. This was caused by my own stupidity. I thought my Windows Mobile 5.0 device was connected to the computer, but instead a different Windows CE 5 device on my desk was connected. I connected the intended device and now it is working again. I have had this problem before when targeting a Windows CE device even when the project is set up for that, so I thought that was happening here. Well this was more literally true than I realized.